# Создать сетку Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Как сделать так, чтобы на десктопе было 12 колонок в ряд, а на мобильных экранах эти 12 колонок отображались по 3 колонки в ряд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">10</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">11</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-1">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```